# Display all the terms within a custom taxonomy

Tags: loop

I am looking to make a few different displays on the home page of terms within certain taxonomies as well as their image field as defined by ACF.

I have been looking online and found 2 main different ways to do this and would like to initially ask what is the difference between the two:?

```
WP_Term_Query();
```

and

```
get_terms();
```

This is the code I have so far but it does not seem to work with the_title() and the_permalink().

Also, it displays the ACF image field of the first result but then repeats the same image for the others.
The ACF custom image field on the term is 'artist_thumbnail_image'

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'               => 'artist',
    'orderby'                => 'name',
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'             => false,
    'meta_key'               => 'artist_featured',
    'meta_value'             => '1',
    'meta_compare'           => '==',
);
$the_query = new WP_Term_Query($args);
foreach ($the_query->get_terms() as $term) { ?>
    <?php echo $term->name; ?>

    <?php
    $featuredartistid = $term->term_id;
    $featuredartist = get_field('artist', $featuredartistid);
    $featuredartistthumbnailimage = get_field('artist_thumbnail_image', $featuredartist);
    $featuredartistthumbnailimagesize = 'thumbnail'; ?>

    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($artistthumbnailimage, $artistthumbnailimagesize); ?>
    </a>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) creates a [`WP_Term_Query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/) and then passed the `$args` to it. It also applies the [`get_terms` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_terms/) to the terms before they're returned. `get_terms()` is, in this case, a convenience function, to use if you don't need all the bells and whistles a `WP_Term_Query` might provide.
2. As far as [`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) and [`the_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/), those functions are meant to work on posts, not taxonomy terms. `the_title()` will only have meaning if you're in [The Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/), I believe. Outside The Loop, you can use [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/), but you'll need to pass it a post or a post ID.
3. Your image problem might be because you're changing from `featuredartistthumbnailimage` and `featuredartistthumbnailimagesize` to `artistthumbnailimage` and `artistthumbnailimagesize` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. My issues were the incorrect `featuredartistthumbnailimagesize` to `artistthumbnailimage`

Plus also I should have been using the `$term` variable passed to the `wp_get_attachment_image`. Not the `$term->id`.

Below is my working code. Hopefully it will help someone.

```
$fa_args = array(
    'taxonomy'               => 'artist',
    'hide_empty'             => false,
    'meta_key'               => 'artist_featured',
    'meta_value'             => '1',
);
$fa_query = new WP_Term_Query($fa_args);
if (!empty($fa_query->terms)) {
    foreach ($fa_query->terms as $fa_term) {

        $fa_id = $fa_term->term_id; // Term ID
        $fa_link = get_term_link($fa_id); // The term link
        $fa_image_id = get_field('artist_thumbnail_image', $fa_term); //Artist Thumbnail Image ID
        $fa_image = wp_get_attachment_image($fa_image_id, 'thumbnail');

        echo $fa_term->name;
        echo '<br>';
        echo $fa_image;
        echo '<br>';

    }
}
```